# Postfix рассылает спам - как найти, откуда растут ноги ?

Tags: postfix

На днях заметил, что **mail.log** буквально сходит с ума, и в него сыпятся сообщения типа:

```
postfix/smtp[19853]: 87D54422C9F: to=<avxing1688@pchome.com.tw>, relay=mxs.pchome.com.tw[211.20.188.150]:25, delay=298085, delays=298063/14/7.1/0.4, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mxs.pchome.com.tw[211.20.188.150] said: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [тут мой ip] (in reply to RCPT TO command))postfix/smtp[19757]: connect to msx-smtp7.hinet.net[168.95.5.69]:25: Connection timed outpostfix/virtual[19996]: 84315422007: to=<root@mydomain.ru>, relay=virtual, delay=0.18, delays=0.12/0/0/0.05, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "root@mydomain.ru")
```

(заменил в тексте имя своего домена на mydomain.ru)

и ещё много всякой весёлости, а на ящик с примерно каждые две-три минуты прилетает сообщение, от **mail delivery system** о том, что что-то не доставлено - обычно какая-то китайская хрень о золотых миллионах. MTA настраивал мастером, который был в комплекте с EHCP, как его настраивать - имею смутные представления, просьба сильно не пинать.

Прошу подсказать, где искать ноги - откуда эта волна хрен знает каких сообщений, какие логи читать, какие конфиги править...

После перекрытия 25 порта на фаерволе шлюза, оно не успоколось.

Comment: Посмотреть очередь    postqueue -p

Comment: [Wiki Open Relay][1][Open Relay Test][2]   [1]: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9   [2]: http://www.mailradar.com/openrelay/

Comment: вернуло дофига много, терминал захлебнулся. очередь я дропнул    `postsuper -d ALL` но ничего не понял =(

Comment: откуда кто слал, нужно было посмотреть... ну теперь новые письма в очереди нужно смотреть

Comment: могу поделиться штукой, которую писал для себя когда-то    postqueue -p | grep -v "^[^0-9A-Z]" | grep -v "^$" | awk '{a[$7]=a[$7]+1} END {for (c in a) {print a[c],c}}' | sort -n | column -tона считает в очереди количество писем от одного отправителя. Писал давно, если кто оптимальнее придумает, буду рад )

Answer (score 1):

Для начала поищите в логах полностью инфу о qid 87D54422C9F (это из пример выше), т.к. как минимум вы должны понять от куда оно вообще попало вам в очередь. По этой инфе можно будет кто или что рассылает спам (обычно там содержится или uid отправившего процесс или хотя бы от куда приконнектился клиент). Ужа на основании этой инфы надо смотреть что делать дальше. То ли бить по рукам какого-то отдельного пользователя, то ли искать мейл бот на хостинге, то ли закрывать опен релей.

Все остальное, гадание на кофейной гуще. Тут важны детали.